# Altium Library Management

Tags: altium

I am new at Altium designer. I just start to work in a company as librarian for Altium. So I'm reading about library management. Sch.lib, Pcb.lib, Int.Lib, Db.lib, Svn.lib

Also, Altium 365 is good for library management for a team worker. But it's not free, as I know.

We are 5 person in a team. So What do you recommend for library management for Altium designer?

Thank you
Kubra

Comment: Just use a local library on a network drive

Comment: Did you work with Altium 365 component templates ? Is it useful ?

Comment: Use Altium 365. It's easy and have great revision control for parts, symbols and landpatterns.

Comment: I have just look for our subscription plan and it doesnt include Altium 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it's pretty easy.

You will start with single SchLib and PcbLib files. At some point later in time you will get problems with inconsistent parameters at which time you will look into other approaches. From then on you will probably want to use a DbLib or SvnDbLib (which is basically the same except the libraries are stored in SVN). With the increased usage of GIT do yourself a favor and store your libraries in GIT and use the DbLib approach. The [celestial library](https://github.com/issus/altium-library) is such a DbLib with libs stored in GIT.

Or you can go all-in with Altium and rely on their A365 product which in turn is .. who would have guessed it - libraries stored in GIT and a DbLib, built together with a nice interface and some goodies which are buggy.

Under no circumstance use IntLib .. they are only good to pack up a project to send it to someone else.

Always ensure your design and your libraries are stored in a GIT repository, do not use Google Drive or OneDrive.

If you have a valid license feel free to join the forum on forum.live.altium.com

Comment: Thank for your comment its very useful.

In the company also they are using Db.Lib. But I want to improve the library.

I need to do some more research on the git library method. It's new for me.

I have a valid license so I will join the forum on forum.live.altium.com

Comment: DbLib is perfectly fine. We're a team of 10 and are using it. It's more important how you store your schematic symbols and footprints so changes can be traced. Also, always ensure that your database/GIT combination stays in sync. Do not rename a footprint which is used at some other place. You can e.g. use issus' Altium library to extract properties automatically and ensure that synchronicity. Requires some coding but you can do lots of cool things.

Comment: - So why its not enough only db.lib . Why do I need to combinate db.lib and git

Comment: Becasue the DbLib itself doesn't store SchLib and PcbLib files. It's just the glue that bringts everything together: SchLib/PcbLib with Part Parameters and a unique Part Identifier

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are few methods you can follow.

1. If you like to use more simple and easy lib, you can Sch.lib, Pcb.lib as a start.
2. After getting quite component on your lib, you can convert them to Int.Lib, so you can easily install and drag it wherever you want.
3. For database lab, i think this will be not needed at start, but if you like to try i recommend you to check out Celestial Altium Library.

I'm currently using Int.Lib because i like to have full control on my lib. Like adding few special notes on my components such as Fabrication code, referral, local base suppliers(Ozdi**n etc. )muadil etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I am not alone in project. And other colleges need to reach the library. So I think intlib. ıts not useful I thınk .

Comment: You can store your intlib on the local server. As a 5 person team we're doing the same